# services vs threads in Android for OpenCV

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv, service

I need to do some intensive background processing by using OpenCV, with the frames received from the smartphone camera. For some processing, my frame-rate drops from 20 FPS to 2 or even 0.3 FPS.

My fist idea was to use threads with handler messages, but because I'm new in android, and looking in the documentation, it seems that services are more suitable for my case scenario.

My background task is not just about sending data, I need the result from that task, so idk what to choose.

Comment: "my frame-rate drops from 20 FPS to 2 or even 0.3" - Memory usage? -> Garbage collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `AsyncTask`. It's easy to use. You can find implementation guide [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)